# Can't archive to proper encode csv in PHP

Tags: php, csv, encoding

I have this function to import a csv.

```
public function csv_to_array($filename, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"')
{

    $header = null;
    $data = array();


    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false)
    {

        $all = 0;

        while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure)) !== false)
        {

            $i=0;
            foreach($row as $string) {
                $row[$i] = utf8_encode($string);
                $i++;
            }

            if(!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            }else{
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
            $all++;
        }

        fclose($handle);

    }

    return $data;
}
```

Some files, who come in ANSI Encoding don't work with str_getcsv or fgetcsv.
I also tried to convert them first with

```
mb_convert_encoding($line, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
```

or with iconv, utf8_encode, ...

In other projects I never stumbled about this issue. Normally some of the above does the trick, but not this time. The whole system and database are set to utf-8. Is there any known work around, how to solve my problem? I'm helpless :(

Comment: How many problem characters are there? Few or many?

Comment: I had this problem too, I just checked if it's utf8 before: [`snippet`](https://git.io/vicjj)

Comment: `ANSI Encoding` is too generic. You need to be absolutely sure the input encoding is `Windows-1252` and not something else.

Comment: Exactly it is Windows-1252. The caracters are depending on the file, but in  all cases there are under 1000 chr per line.

Comment: Tried the snipped, also doesn't work. Already tried similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using any of the encoding functions right. If you want to convert **from Windows-1252 to UTF-8** neither of these will work:

```
 utf8_encode($string)
```

... converts **from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8** ([reference](http://php.net/utf8_encode)).

```
mb_convert_encoding($line, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
```

... converts **from UTF-8 to Windows-1252** ([reference](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)).

When you're in a hurry just read the docs ;-)